# am new to python, please share logic for below concept

Tags: python

Eg:

```
ECE_student_list = [['section-1', [["sai",'science'], ["rama",'maths']]],
                ['section-2', [["seetha",'science'], ["ravana",'maths']]]]
```

I have to print student name and subject by passing key as section name.

for Eg : if the key is 'section-1'  first student then it should print "sai",'science'
second student ,then it should print "rama",'maths'

please share the logic in python.

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: As mentioned, read about [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). Play around with the code with that in mind, and then update your question with your own code attempt of this and explain what difficulties you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Won't share the code directly. That you have to learn and experiment on your own. Although I can tell you what you can expect as your output.

You can create a dictionary in python and add section-1, section-2 as the keys and the list of students as value for each key.

Your dictionary structure will be something like this:

```
{
  'section-1' : [
    {'sai':'science'},
    {'rama':'math'}
  ],
  'section-2':[
    {'sai':'science'},
    {'rama':'math'}
  ]
}
```

Comment: yeah thank you  for the reply. please share cod for that

Comment: Please write some code of your own then ask why it isn't working - unless, of course, it does!